# redirect STDERR of eval to /dev/null in perl

Tags: perl, eval

```
eval {require $testRequirePath};
```

While running the above, if there is syntax error in `$testRequirePath` file, then it prints it to the STDOUT. I want to redirect it to `/dev/null`. How can i do it?

Comment: no, it doesn't print syntax errors to STDOUT or anywhere else.  show what output you are actually getting, please.

Comment: @ysth: This is the output im getting on the screen. *Bareword found where operator expected at Group2.pm line 117, near ") sendCmd" (Missing operator before sendCmd?)*

Comment: An `eval BLOCK` hides all errors. If you are seeing an error message then it is because the calling code has chosen to declare defeat. Please show your *full code*. It really looks like you have a problem in `Group2.pm`. If you would like help with that, then please show the twenty or so lines around line 117.

Comment: @Borodin: There is a semi colon missing. I did that on purpose to create this issue.  Because I don't want such error to get printed on STDOUT when I add new groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is a warning, not an error; errors will be captured by the eval and placed in $@.  To suppress warnings also, you can just do:

```
eval { local $SIG{__WARN__} = sub {}; require $testRequirePath }
```